# How to use DataTables script with an already filled table

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, datatables, model

I'm working on an MVC project. So this is my problem, i already filled my table body with my data from my model. but know i want to integrate dataTables to a more responsive and usefull design of the table, 
At the same time, I want to continue using model.field to get specific references in my data
To resume, i want to integrate jquery datatables without having to insert data ( which is alerady existing in the table)
Here is the code that i've done yet. any idea of how to do it?

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.MCD>
@using WebApplication11.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
}

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column sortable" id="sample_1">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OUTRET)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GLOBALRET)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SETT_DATE)
            </th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OUTRET)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GLOBALRET)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SETT_DATE)
                </td>



            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
</table>

}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    .
    .
    .

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: "Index",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#sample_1').DataTable({
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        data: result,
                        buttons: [{
                            extend: 'collection',
                            text: 'Export',
                            buttons:

                                [{ extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-primary' },
                                { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-primary' },
                                { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn-primary' },
                                { extend: 'pdf', className: 'btn-primary' },
                                { extend: 'print', className: 'btn-primary' }
                                ]

                        }],
                    })

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");

                },


            });
        }
        )
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a table in HTML you can initialise DataTables on it once the page has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // make sure the document has finished loading, or use <script> tags at the bottom of the HTML
    $('#tableId').DataTable();
});
```

You can set options in the usual way. If you reload your table you will need to re-initialise DataTables, but if your page reloads anyway this will not be a problem.

Comment: can you be more explicit, i'm not sure how to do that,
I tried adding on load to my script :
 onload: function () {
                            $('#sample_1').DataTable({...
                   
but datatable is not rendering, i'm getting my old table as usual

Comment: update: i figured it out! i just had to put it inside the @section scripts{} and it works just fine
Thank you